# Ruby's Single Inheritance Issue

Tags: ruby, oop, inheritance, conceptual

I need some help defining an example that illustrates why single inheritance in Ruby is a problem.
The problem cannot be solved with single class inheritance.

Consider this an abstract example of the limitations Ruby faces with OO. I've tried to come up with a few examples but keep coming up short.

The idea is to then use a Module to provide a workaround to this issue that Ruby faces.

Any help is greatly appreciated. If you see my example below, it be great to get any feedback on whether it proves the above question or not.

Person superclass and Pet superclass don't belong to the same class hierarchy but share the same instance method swim. For that reason, the swim instance method is placed within a module and mixin to each superclass.

```
module Swimming
    def swim
      puts 'I can swim'.
    end
end

class Person

    include Swimming

    def initialize(name)
      @name = name
    end
end

class Boy < Person 
end

class Pet
    include Swimming

    def initialize(name)
      @name = name
    end
end

class Fish < Pet
end

new_boy = Boy.new('Oliver')
new_fish = Fish.new('Ronald')
```

Comment: Hard to come up with a problem that requires multiclass inheritance to solve, especially when you have mixin modules.

Comment: Yeah, mixins pretty much solve the inheritance problem for most practical use cases. You'd probably find it easier to do something like this in a language like Java that doesn't have mixins or traits.

Comment: I guess what I'm getting at is I need a problem that can't be solved with single inheritance and can only be solved with mixin

Comment: What do you need this for? If it is so hard to come up with an example then maybe your "single inheritance in Ruby is a problem" premise is a bit off.

Comment: @muistooshort well just because I can't think of it, doesn't mean the SO forums can't either..... Hence why I asked the question, where maybe one of you have encountered a perfect example of this... thanks for your help.

Comment: Multiple inheritance can be avoided by using mixins, or in other languages, protocols. There's no problem that can't be solved with single inheritance. There's always a way, the question is how ugly is the solution vs. multiple-inheritance.

Comment: I'm confused. You claim that single inheritance is a problem, yet are unable to come up with even a *single* example of where single inheritance is a problem? Then how do you know it is a problem?

Comment: @JörgWMittag actually, I do provide an example but I'm not sure if it's a perfect example where single inheritance from a class can replace a module. We know for a fact that in Ruby you can only inherit from one class, but mixin as many modules as you want. So you can either try to help find a perfect example where single inheritance forces the creation of a module... or simply don't comment at all. Seems useless to provide a comment without any positive feedback. Thanks

Comment: But mixin inheritance *is* class inheritance in Ruby. The mixin simply becomes the superclass.

Answer (score 1):

Mixins are used any time you want to include functionality from multiple places. Some other languages use multiple inheritance instead.

```
module Swimming; end
module Bicycling; end

class Person
  include Swimming
  include Bicycling
end
```

If there was a class which used only one mixin, then it could easily be changed to an inheritance-based implementation:

```
class Swimming; end # not a module
class Amoeba < Swimming
end
```

But something similar couldn't be done for the Person class without creating an intermediary class which wraps the modules.

```
class SwimmingAndBicycling
  include Swimming
  include Bicycling
end
class Person < SwimmingAndBicycling
end
```

So modules are really the only simple way to combine 2+ pieces of functionality into a third. Ruby is a pretty flexible language and there are ways to get around this such as manually copying methods from one class to another. But this is the standard approach.

Also it's worth mentioning that classes and modules have some pragmatic differences which I'm not covering here. For example, in inheritance all instance and class methods are copied over, but with modules this depends on whether include or extend is called.

Comment: `include` simply makes the module the superclass of the class it is included into (more precisely, it creates a class which shares its method, constant, class variable, and instance variable table with the module, and makes that class the superclass of the class). So, mixin inheritance in Ruby *is* single class inheritance. (`extend` is more or less the same thing, it is roughly equivalent to `singleton_class.include`.) So, you are, in fact, not demonstrating a problem with Ruby's single class inheritance, but rather demonstrating that Ruby's single class inheritance is not a problem!